# Opening files from uimenu in matlab

Tags: matlab

i am still working at my project and i again i hit a wall.

In this case i am trying to open a .pdf file from uimenu, i have searched through functions, i think i found the right one:

```
x = 'D:\MATLAB\Author.pdf';
y = 'D:\MATLAB\Bibliography.pdf';
f=uimenu('Label','ProjectData');
uimenu(f,'Label','Author','Callback','fopen(x)');
uimenu(f,'Label','Bibliography','Callback','fopen(y)');
uimenu(f,'Label','Close','Callback','close',...
'Separator','on','Accelerator','Q');
```

But the problem is that when i click on author or bibliography nothing happens, no errors, nothing.
The only thing that appears in command window is this :

ans =

```
    -1
```

The .pdf files are in the same folder as the rest of the .m files.

Please help, Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because MATLAB can't open your file.

From the `fopen` documentation (available [here)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) (the bold font is from me):

> fileID = fopen(filename) opens the file, filename, for binary read
>   access, and returns an integer file identifier equal to or greater
>   than 3. MATLAB® reserves file identifiers 0, 1, and 2 for standard
>   input, standard output (the screen), and standard error, respectively.
>
> **If fopen cannot open the file, then fileID is -1.**

So MATLAB is giving this fileID of -1. If you want MATLAB to open the appropriate application for your pdf file (i.e. Adobe Acrobat), you can use [open](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/open.html).

If you want to actually open pdf as images in MATLAB, there is probably some function on the [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/).

Hope that helps!